# How to read geolocation using adb shell

Tags: shell, geolocation

Is it possible to read geolocation data (either one provided by GPS or by GSM) using adb shell?

Comment: Possibly related: [Stack Overflow - How to get GPS data from Android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501719/how-to-get-gps-data-from-android-phone)

Comment: @lou…stephen is correct, this is a duplicate. Check out the link he provided and read the accepted answer by __keir finlow-bates__.

Answer (score 1):

Input `adb shell dumpsys location` and look under "Last Known Locations".